# When I am adding items to a sql db table from .csv file using J-Meter, why am I getting 500 Internal Server Error periodically off back of 200 reponse

Tags: jmeter

I am new on here and new to J-Meter so bear with me.

I am trying to add items to a table on sql from a .csv file (Columns in .csv file are 'id', 'text', 'userId').  200000000021,01232456459,john.smith@example.com.  id and userId are same values.  Text increments + 1 each time.  About 40 records in the file.

I am using a Bearer token as Authorization, but each time I am running the test (json parameterized request) , I am noticing in the Results Tree Viewer I am getting a 200 but several 500 responses, then another 200 etc

Why won't all my requests appear as 200?  Do I need to add a delay between each request?

Results Tree Viewer

[image: 1]

I would ideally need this running over 3 threads

Thread Group properties

[image: 2]

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Expecting to see 200 responses against all requests processed

Comment: any error message in Response body?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Status 500 means [Internal Server Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500)

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) `500 Internal Server Error` server error response code indicates that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
>
> This error response is a generic "catch-all" response. Usually, this indicates the server cannot find a better 5xx error code to response. Sometimes, server administrators log error responses like the 500 status code with more details about the request to prevent the error from happening again in the future.

1. So first of all check "Response Data" tab of the [s](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener for any suspicious entries, it might be the case the server tells you what went wrong.
2. If there is nothing useful there - check your server and/or database logs, it might be the case you will be able to figure out the reason from there
3. Then you could try running your test several more times to see if the behaviour is [repeatable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeatability), i.e. whether the same requests with the same data failing all the time
4. It might be connected with concurrency, i.e. only one request is allowed at the moment, try decreasing the number of concurrent users to 1 and see whether it resolves your issue
5. Check [Sharing Mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-csv-dataset-config) setting of the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config), if it's different from the default value of `All threads` it might be the case 2 users are sending the same request and your server and/or database doesn't allow duplicate values.